# Creating a Infinite While Loop Errors in Java

Tags: java, string, while-loop

I'm trying to implement a **infinite while loop** into my word frequency **java** code. The goal of this code was to create a program using main method java to analysis a piece text which has been entered from a user.

They do this by entering the text into a scanner which is then analysed by the program.

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class WordFreq { 

public static void main (String[] args) {

     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter text: "); 
            String s;
                s = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("" + s);

          String[] strings = s.split(" ");
          int[] counts = new int[6];
          for(String str : strings)
               if(str.length() < counts.length) counts[str.length()] += 1;
          for(int i = 1; i < counts.length; i++)
              System.out.println(i + " letter words: " + counts[i]);




          input.close();}
}
```

The user then can re enter a piece of text to be analysed over and over again. 
I have this piece of code, which has a infinite while already in, but when I try to merge the two I keep getting errors.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class WhileLoop {



public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line="";


    while((line=scan.nextLine())!=null)
    {

        String tokens [] = line.split(" ");
        for(int i=0;i&lt;tokens.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(tokens[i]);
        }


    }


}
```

I'm not the Best at java and I'm not expecting anyone to just hand me code, but if someone could give me a hint in what I should do or just point me the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code. This is horrible to read - always review what a post is going to look like before submitting it. Additionally "I keep getting errors" doesn't provide *nearly* enough information. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-checklist

Comment: Post code you have along with it's errors. People will not merge these programs for you.

Comment: you said that you're getting an error. where is the error?

Comment: have a exit string like -99 or something and loop while your input not equal to that magic number

Comment: what do you mean by `when I try to merge the two I keep getting errors` - where is the merged code? What is the error?

Comment: I'm trying to input the While into the first block of code, but when I merge them, it only prints out what the user has entered and not the analysis along with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not clarified how do you actually merged your code and what kinds of errors ar eyou getting but your `while` loop is not good. You need to wait for user input INSIDE an "infinite" loop.

```
while(true){ //Infinite loop
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(in.hasNextLine())//Check for input
        System.out.println(in.nextLine()); //Process input
}
```

This way every time the user pressed 'Enter' you process his input.Of course you can do anything you like with `in.nextLine()' or`in.next()` and your while loop could have an ending condition cause i doubt you want an 100% infinite loop, but the structure should be the same. Hope this helps.

EDIT: Try the following code:

```
while(true){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter text: "); 
    String s;
    s = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("" + s);

    String[] strings = s.split(" ");
    int[] counts = new int[6];
    for(String str : strings)
        if(str.length() < counts.length) counts[str.length()] += 1;
    for(int i = 1; i < counts.length; i++)
        System.out.println(i + " letter words: " + counts[i]);

}
```

Although its quite unlikely you need a true infinite loop, so consider putting some stopping condition in your while loop.

Comment: Thank you, and I'm very sorry for this confusion and the lack of information within my post.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit confusing, but let me try anyway.
If you merge the two blocks of code then you should try printing count[i] instead of token[i] in the while loop. And the limit of the loop should be count.Length not token.Length.
Now, if I am not wrong, this would print the frequency of 1 to 5 lettered words infinitely taking in your inputs from the first block of the code.